# How can you grab user input on a search and "append" it on the end of an HTM url in <a> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, django, url, user-input

So I have a basic search functionality using Django and HTML.

```
<input type="text" name="searchterms" id="pubsearch" style="width: 90%"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

I want to take the searchterms and append it to the end of a pagination URL which the user has the option to click, specifically where I've written the word "HERE".

```
{% if pubs.has_next %}
      <a href="?page={{ pubs.next_page_number }}&&searchterms= HERE ">next</a>
{% endif %}
```

How does one go about doing this? Do I need to catch the user input variable in javascript and then pass it along? Not sure how to go about it, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery

Comment: the input is filled on client side, so yes, you need javascript for that (unless you don't care if the page is reloaded in the process). You should give an id to the link so its url can be easily edited with js to add the parameter

Comment: @Kaddath, can you elaborate? How do I append to the end of URL using javascript?

Comment: Do you expect the url to update after you submit to the server?

Comment: @epascarello no, it doesn't have to update. I have that taken care of in my views.py

Comment: let's say your link id is 'myLink' and the input value 'yourValue', with jQuery you would do something like `$("#myLink").attr("href", $("#myLink").attr("href") + "&searchterms=" + yourValue);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django form, You may bind the input value like

```
{% if pubs.has_next %}
  <a href="?page={{ pubs.next_page_number }}&&searchterms={{form.fields.searchterms}}">next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Any nice, easy way to do it like this if I am not using django form? I am collecting the variable in views.py like so:     search = request.GET['searchterms']